Regarding Torque of DC Motor with PWM, Atmega328 and MOSfet
I am trying to develop a system having a DC motor (geared 12v 200rpm). There's a rotary encoder to adjust the RPM of the motor. I am using Atmega328 as the main MCU. To drive the motor I am using IRF840 Power MOSFET. The PWM frequency I am using is 8Khz right now. The system is running good BUT theres an issue regarding torque of the motor. At low RPMs the motor is not delivering enough torque. As the RPMs increase the torque increases. I know the torque is directly proportional to the current. The circuit i am using is like this:
I have tried other PWM frequencies like 16Khz and 12Khz but nothing changed apart from the ringing noise coming from the motor coils. The coil resistance of the motor is 12Ohm. The code I am using for this is
#define rotLeft 2
#define rotRight 3
int currentStateA,lastStateA;
int pwmValue = 90;


void setup()
 { 
  int val;
   DDRD |= (1<<PD6);    //Fast PWM output at OC0A pin

  OCR0A = 90;   
    TCCR0A |= (1<<COM0A1) | (1<<WGM01) | (1<<WGM00);    //Non-Inverting Fast PWM mode 3 using OCR A unit
    //TCCR0B |= (1<<CS10);  //No-Prescalar
  TCCR0B = 0b00000010;
  pinMode(rotLeft, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(rotRight, INPUT_PULLUP);
 }
  
void loop(){

setPWM();

}

void setPWM() {

  currentStateA = digitalRead(rotLeft);
  if (currentStateA != lastStateA && currentStateA == 1) {


    if (digitalRead(rotRight) != currentStateA) {
      pwmValue = pwmValue - 3;
      if (pwmValue < 90) {
        pwmValue = 90;
       
      }
      OCR0A = pwmValue;
     

    } else {

      pwmValue = pwmValue + 3;
      if (pwmValue > 250) {
        pwmValue = 250;
        
      }
      OCR0A = pwmValue;
      
    }
  }

  lastStateA = currentStateA;
  delay(1);
}

I have a pre built working sample of the system that I am making. The motor used that system is 6v 200RPM and mine is 12v 200RPM. I connected that 6v motor with my built by reducing the VCC from my power source to 7v but it didnt gave THAT torque which the original system is giving. I tried to peek into the circuit of the original and they have used an SMD Power transistor having code "A091". So, can this problem be fixed? Any help would be highly appreciated!
~Vic

Try it with a much lower PWM frequency like 100 Hz for comparison. The result can give a hint here.
